# Getting n number of row value in string format from datatable object

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

The below data-table has this below structure.

```
RCDID    EmployeeID  LogDate     LogTime    TerminalID  InOut
1682284  362426      07/01/2017  08:38:46   HO001        0
1682286  362426      07/02/2017  08:32:04   HO001        0
1682287  362426      07/02/2017  08:32:06   HO001        0
1682289  362426      07/03/2017  08:35:08   HO001        0
1682291  362426      07/04/2017  08:38:23   HO001        0
1682292  362426      07/04/2017  08:38:25   HO001        0
```

How can i retrieve the second value of LogTime for certain date in form of string.

for example for date `07/02/2017` retrieved value will be  `08:32:06`.

and for 07/04/2017 retrieved value will be `08:38:25`

Comment: For `07/02/2017`, why it cannot be `08:32:04`? Do you mean, that you want the last `LogTime` for given date?

Comment: no the second LogTime for given date

Comment: @Ayman Have you tried my post?

Comment: yes it didn't work it shows this error " Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string logTime = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                          .Where(d => d.Field<DateTime>("LogDate").Date == new DateTime(2017, 4, 7).Date)
                          .Select(s => s.Field<string>("LogTime"))
                          .ToList()[1];
```

this will return the second value from your table if the `LogTime` is string, if not change `s.Field<string>("LogTime")` part to match your data type.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement extension method for DataTable class follow as

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
            new DataColumn("RCDID", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("EmployeeID", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("LogDate", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("LogTime", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("TerminalID", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("InOut   ", typeof(int)),
        });

        dt.Rows.Add(1682284, 362426, "07/01/2017", "08:38:46", "HO001", 0);
        dt.Rows.Add(1682286, 362426, "07/02/2017", "08:32:04", "HO001", 0);
        dt.Rows.Add(1682287, 362426, "07/02/2017", "08:32:06", "HO001", 0);
        dt.Rows.Add(1682289, 362426, "07/03/2017", "08:35:08", "HO001", 0);
        dt.Rows.Add(1682291, 362426, "07/04/2017", "08:38:23", "HO001", 0);
        dt.Rows.Add(1682292, 362426, "07/04/2017", "08:38:25", "HO001", 0);


        var result = dt.GetValueFromColumnByColumn("LogDate", "07/04/2017", "LogTime");
    }
}

public static class DataTableExtension
{
    public static object GetValueFromColumnByColumn(this DataTable dataTable, string byColumn, object valueOfByColumn, string fromColumn)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            if (row[byColumn] == valueOfByColumn)
            {
                return row[fromColumn];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: the data are not fixed i am getting data from database then i assign it to datatable